# How to get a TokenStream of a document's field to be used for highlighting?

Tags: java, lucene

## The Problem

I'm currently working on a project using `Lucene 8.1.0`, pure `Lucene`-not `Solr`. I would like to add highlighting to the results that get displayed based on the user query. The problem i'm facing is that i can't figure out a way to get a `TokenStream` of a field on a specified document. The field i'm trying to access is indexed using term vectors, along with other `FieldType` parameters.

## What I tried

The [official documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TokenSources.html) on the TokenSources class lists almost all of the methods used in the past, as **deprecated**. I've searched far and wide, all the guides/posts I've found are relatively old and all of them use TokenSources and one of the **deprecated** methods.  I'd be willing to use the function `getTermVectorTokenStreamOrNull()` but I don't understand how to use the Fields parameter and what to pass there.  (I can't instantiate a `Fields` object, since it's abstract, and none of the direct known subclasses make sense to me or how to use them).

The current solution i have is to get a `TokenStream` the following way:

```java
String text = hit.get(field.label);
Analyzer analyzer = new ClassicAnalyzer();
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(field.label, text);
TextFragment[] fragments = highlighter.getBestTextFragments(tokenStream, text, false, 5);
```

What I actually need help is, how to use the term vectors of a field and how to get a `TokenStream` for setting up the `Highlighter`.
*If*  you think this is wrong and I should use the `getBestFragments​(Analyzer analyzer, String fieldName, String text, int maxNumFragments)` method from [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html), then that means I won't be needing the term vectors. But from what I can gather, using term vectors helps with performance on search times with the trade-off of index size. What is your advice?
*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my problem. The thing I was missing was [`TokenStreamFromVector`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TokenStreamFromTermVector.html) class. `TokenStreamFromVector` extends `TokenStream` so I'm able to plug it in the `getBestFragments()` method.
Gonna leave this up for anyone lost and looking for the same thing. Looking through the [USE](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/class-use/TokenStream.html) tabs really helped but I don't know why `TokenStreamFromVector` isn't linked as a subclass in the [`TokenStream`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html) page.
(I know it's in a different package but still, there's no way to reach the [`TokenStreamFromVector`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TokenStreamFromTermVector.html) page quickly and through the normal workflow.)

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in Lucene javadoc https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/TokenSources.html#getTermVectorTokenStreamOrNull-java.lang.String-org.apache.lucene.index.Fields-int- .

> tvFields - from IndexReader.getTermVectors(int). Possibly null.

So all you need is `IndexReader` to get `Fields`. And int parameter is docID, which you get from your search result, as `topDocs.scoreDocs[i].doc` value.